With gbd debugger it works but not with vsc
#include <stdio.h>
#define size 100
int main(){
    int peppe[size],n,i,j;
    float somma;

    do {
        printf("Inserisci il numero di elementi: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
    } while (n <= 0 || n > size);

    for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
        printf("Inserisci il valore %d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &peppe[i]);
    }

    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        if(peppe[i]>=0){
            somma += peppe[i];
            j++;
        }
    }

    printf( "La media dei valori positivi è: %.2lf", somma/j );

    return 0;
}

i'm trying to have the average number of the positive ones in a vector but it gives me numbers too small.
This is vsc:
Inserisci il numero di elementi: 5
Inserisci il valore 0: 3
Inserisci il valore 1: 4
Inserisci il valore 2: 5
Inserisci il valore 3: -8
Inserisci il valore 4: -7
La media dei valori positivi è: 1.09


You should run your program in a debugger and watch variable content while you step through your instructions. Do they contain the values you expect them to hold?

In C local variables are not initialized. They contain an undetermined value. It appears to work in the debugger because these variables are probably set to zero initially by chance.

It is common that various bad compilers/debuggers set all of the stack space to zero when you launch a program in debug mode. Which in turn is a very common source of bugs that the bad compiler/debugger hid during development - you won't notice the bugs until they surface in release mode.

Need to initialize variables in a first place:
int j = 0;
float somma = 0;

From the documentation from cppreference.com about C language initialization of the local variables:

If an initializer is not provided:

objects with automatic storage duration are initialized to indeterminate values

...
If an indeterminate value is used as an argument to any standard library call, the behavior is undefined. Otherwise, the result of any expression involving indeterminate values is an indeterminate value (e.g. int n;, n may not compare equal to itself and it may appear to change its value on subsequent reads)

so in your example they are being initialized to indeterminate values.
